# codeigniter subdomain uses same controllers as domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, subdomain

I want to create a mobile version of my site to a subdomain m.mysite.com and I saw that the best way will be to create the subdomain with coresponding folder ,in this case m, and make the index.php file to load the controllers and any data it needs except the views folder from the main domain.

Could anyone tell me how the index.php file should look in that case.

My main index.php looks like this

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1'){

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

} else {

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

}



$system_path = "system";

$application_folder=strncasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/admin',6)==0 ? "app/admin":"app/frontend";

    //  $application_folder = "app/frontend";



if (realpath($system_path) !== FALSE){ $system_path = realpath($system_path).'/'; }

$system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';

if ( ! is_dir($system_path)){ exit("Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)); }

define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

define('EXT', '.php');

define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));

define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));

define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));     

if (is_dir($application_folder)){

    define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');

} else {        

    if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/')){ exit("Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".SELF); }

    define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');

}
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bratislava');

require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter'.EXT;
```

Comment: Seperate mobile versions of a website are a dying trend. Responsive design is the way to go. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Comment: This is a kind of responsive design I just want to have an subdomain to redirect every users with specfic mobile software, this for a better experience and to avoid the check is_mobile on every page load